# How to stop script from automatically closing?

Tags: scripting, output, exe, executable, autoit

I open an .exe file but the script immediately closes after opening it. How can I prevent the script from closing?

```
Local $engine= "C:\Users\Davis\Desktop\chessEngine\stockfish-5-win\Windows\stockfish_14053109_32bit.exe"

Run($engine, "", @SW_MAXIMIZE, $STDOUT_CHILD)
```

Removing `$STOUT_CHILD` from `Run()` leaves the script open after executing, but I need this to read output from the program. Why is this happening?

Answer (score 1):

```
Local $engine = "C:\Users\Davis\Desktop\chessEngine\stockfish-5-win\Windows\stockfish_14053109_32bit.exe"

Local $iPID = Run($engine, "", @SW_MAXIMIZE, $STDOUT_CHILD) 

ProcessWaitClose($iPID)
```

Answer (score 0):

This ist an example how to get output from a DOS command.

```
ConsoleWrite(_getDOSOutput('ipconfig /all') & @CRLF)

Func _getDOSOutput($command)
    Local $text = '', $Pid = Run('"' & @ComSpec & '" /c ' & $command, '', @SW_HIDE, 2 + 4)
    While 1
            $text &= StdoutRead($Pid, False, False)
            If @error Then ExitLoop
            Sleep(10)
    WEnd
    Return StringStripWS($text, 7)
EndFunc   ;==>_getDOSOutput
```